# Last id get using php oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I want to get the last id inserted but i don;t know how to get it in oracle. Any help will be appreciated. Below is my query.

```
$query = oci_parse($con,"INSERT INTO USER_LOGIN (USERNAME, PASSWORD, CNIC, ROLE_ID, PICTURE) 
                  VALUES ('$Username', '$Password', '$CNIC', '$Role', '$Filename')");
```

**Get above id:** (don't know)

```
$OK = oci_parse($con,"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM USER_LOGIN");

oci_execute($OK);
$row = oci_fetch_array($OK, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);

if($row)
{
  $USERID = $row['USER_ID'];
}
```

Comment: What is the "above ID"?  Is there an `id` column in `user_login` that is populated from a sequence using a trigger on `user_login`?  If so, what is the name of that sequence?  Is `last_insert_id()` a function that you defined?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve (see Justin's questions). But if you want the trigger populated id of the user_login table back to your code you can use the returning clause.

```
$query = oci_parse($con,"INSERT INTO USER_LOGIN (USERNAME, PASSWORD, CNIC, ROLE_ID, PICTURE) 
                  VALUES ('$Username', '$Password', '$CNIC', '$Role', '$Filename')
                  RETURNING YOUR_ID
                  INTO :LAST_INS_ID");
oci_bind_by_name($query, ':LAST_INS_ID', $theNewID, 8);
```